# Error when creating a div with many elements with innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have to create this div element with DOM and javascript:

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
<span>Transport</span>
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>Classic mail</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>UPS Delivery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>Private jet</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i try this:

```
var divHriV = createElement('div', 'divHriV', 'divHriVcss');
var dd = createElement('div', 'dd');
dd.setAttribute("class","wrapper-dropdown-3");
dd.setAttribute("tabIndex",1);
var htmldd = "<span>Transport</span><ul class='dropdown'><li><a href='#'><i class='icon-envelope icon-large'></i>Classic mail</a></li><li><a href='#'><i class='icon-truck icon-large'></i>UPS Delivery</a></li><li><a href='#'><i class='icon-plane icon-large'></i>Private jet</a></li></ul>";
dd.innerHTML(htmldd);
divHriV.appendChild(dd.childNodes);
```

but when i load page a message like

> TypeError: string is not a function

Thanks

Comment: `innerHTML = htmldd;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Comment: Why creating just a div with DOM, if you are creating a span and a whole list as a string innerHTML?

Comment: What is this `createElement(x,y,z)`?

Comment: @epascarello https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Comment: @nem Oh I know what `document.createElement("div")` is... That is not the same thing as what the OP has. If you run what the OP has, you will get `ReferenceError: createElement is not defined` What the OP has is some custom method that is creating an element.

Comment: @epascarello sorry about that, i responded quicker then I read your comment :). you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change: (added @epascarello's suggestion)

```
var dd = createElement('div', 'dd');
<!-- ... -->
dd.innerHTML(htmldd);
```

To:

```
var dd = createElement('div');
<!-- ... -->
dd.innerHTML = htmldd;
```